# How to use FontAwesome Icon on TinyMCE?

Tags: php, jquery, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I know a way to fontsize-change implement like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector : 'textarea',
        toolbar  : 'fontsizeselect',
    });
</script>

<textarea name="aaa"></textarea>
```

That generate text menu

```
<span class="mce-txt">Font Sizes</span>
```

[image]

But I dont like it. I wanna change this text to icon like this.

[image]

I have been searched tinymce all icon, but there are no font-icon.

[image]

So I think this solution is use FontAwesome.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    span.mce-txt:before {
        content: "\f301";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
    }
</style>
```

But that is not show. just display "." only.

How can I use FontAwesome Icon?

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by fixing two mistakes:

1. content value is `"\f031"`, not `"\f301"`.
2. `font-family` did not apply, so I use `!important`

This may work:

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    [aria-label^="Font Sizes"] .mce-txt:before {
        content: "\f031";
        font-family: FontAwesome !important;
    }
</style>
```

http://codepen.io/qwe001/pen/VKPqqv

Answer (score 0):

The code that controls what you see on that toolbar button is in `tinymce/classes/ui/FormatControls.js`

In TinyMCE 4.4.3 on line 507 you will find this:

```
editor.addButton('fontsizeselect', function() {
        var items = [], defaultFontsizeFormats = '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt';
        var fontsize_formats = editor.settings.fontsize_formats || defaultFontsizeFormats;

        each(fontsize_formats.split(' '), function(item) {
            var text = item, value = item;
            // Allow text=value font sizes.
            var values = item.split('=');
            if (values.length > 1) {
                text = values[0];
                value = values[1];
            }
            items.push({text: text, value: value});
        });

        return {
            type: 'listbox',
            text: 'Font Sizes',
            tooltip: 'Font Sizes',
            values: items,
            fixedWidth: true,
            onPostRender: createListBoxChangeHandler(items, 'fontsize'),
            onclick: function(e) {
                if (e.control.settings.value) {
                    editor.execCommand('FontSize', false, e.control.settings.value);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Instead of the `text` attribute you can provide an `image` or `icon` attribute that will allow you to reference an image of your choosing for the toolbar button.

*I would note that using CSS to change the UI of TinyMCE may work now but as TinyMCE evolves there is no guarantee the CSS will remain the same so your CSS trick could easily stop working in the future.  Using the TinyMCE APIs to display the image would not suffer from similar issues over time.*